# New words invented but how to propagate?

Tags: dictionaries, neologisms

To write is to invent words, and one invents words from everyday experiences. Today during a long disGussion with a juvenile mind I thought up diaPERtribe, evidently from diatribe and diaper. Is there a way to get such words "recognized" somehow?

Comment: Get people to use them...

Comment: Pay a maker of hit movies to put your words in the mouth of a popular character.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for "a way to get such words recognized" is about resources, which the Help Centre says is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for assistance with marketing, rather than understanding English grammar or usage.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using them and see if other people also find them useful. Most neologisms disappear unless they fill a real need (eg. describing something that didn't exist before) so don't get your hopes up.

If, after several years, the word is widely used then it may get put into dictionaries:

> A word gets into a dictionary when it is used by many people who all agree that it means the same thing. If your toddler nephew invented a great word that the English language simply can’t do without, don’t write to us to recommend that it be added to the dictionary. Use it. First, you drop the word into your conversation and writing, then others pick it up; the more its use spreads, the more likely it will be noticed by dictionary editors, or lexicographers. If your nephew’s word is one that English speakers decide we need, it has a good chance of getting into the dictionary.

[How a Word Gets Into the Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/how-does-a-word-get-into-the-dictionary) (Merriam-Webster)